# how to filter textfile form asset to show only spesific result

Tags: android

im loading textfile from assets and show in listview using json in my textfile somany schools i paste my file_name.json below problem is i want to filter to show only spesific school which name is `"Middle Schools"` how do i filter this line   `JSONObject json2 = new JSONObject(jsonresult);` to display only that school which name is `"MiddleSchool"`

```
 public String loadJSONFromAsset() {
    String json = null;
    try {

        InputStream is = getAssets().open("file_name.json");

        int size = is.available();

        byte[] buffer = new byte[size];

        is.read(buffer);

        is.close();

        json = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");
        jsonresult=json;

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
    return json;

}
                    JSONObject json2 = new JSONObject(jsonresult);

        status = json2.getString("status");
        if (status.equals("1")) {
            message = "data";

            JSONArray school = json2.getJSONArray("data");

            for (int i = 0; i < school.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject object = school.getJSONObject(i);

                Category_ID.add(Long.parseLong(object
                        .getString("school_id")));
                Category_name.add(object.getString("name"));
            }
        }
        else {
                message = "error";
        }
        }
```

Text file:

```
     {"status":1,"data":[
       {"school_id":"321","name":"Chavez","phone":"","email":"",
      "address":"","information":"","image":"","calendar_id":"2","id":"147","level_id":"1",
      "title":"Elementary Schools"},  

  {"school_id":"319","name":"Central","phone":"","email":"", 
 "address":"","information":"","image":"","calendar_id":"2",
 "id":"145","level_id":"1","title":"Elementary Schools"},

  {"school_id":"318","name":"Carver","phone":"","email":"",
"address":"","information":"","image":"","calendar_id":"2",
"id":"144","level_id":"1","title":"Elementary Schools"},

 {"school_id":"317","name":"Carson","phone":"","email":"",
 "address":"","information":"","image":"","calendar_id":"2","id":"143",
 "level_id":"1","title":"Elementary Schools"},

 {"school_id":"316","name":"Cadman","phone":"","email":"",
 "address":"","information":"","image":"","calendar_id":"1",
 "id":"142","level_id":"1","title":"Elementary Schools"},

{"school_id":"315","name":"Cabrillo","phone":"","email":"",
 "address":"","information":"","image":"","calendar_id":"1",
 "id":"141","level_id":"1","title":"Elementary Schools"},

 {"school_id":"314","name":"Burbank","phone":"","email":"",
 "address":"","information":"","image":"","calendar_id":"2",
"id":"140","level_id":"1","title":"Elementary Schools"},

  {"school_id":"313","name":"Boone","phone":"","email":"",
"address":"","information":"","image":"","calendar_id":"2",
"id":"139","level_id":"1","title":"Elementary Schools"},

 {"school_id":"498","name":"Zamorano","phone":"","email":"",
"address":"","information":"","image":"","calendar_id":"2",
"id":"324","level_id":"1","title":"Elementary Schools"},

  {"school_id":"451","name":"Pershing","phone":"","email":"",
  "address":"","information":"","image":"","calendar_id":"1",
  "id":"277","level_id":"2","title":"Middle Schools"},

  {"school_id":"454","name":"Preuss","phone":"","email":"",
 "address":"","information":"","image":"","calendar_id":"1",
  "id":"280","level_id":"2","title":"Middle Schools"},

 {"school_id":"457","name":"Riley","phone":"","email":"",
 "address":"","information":"","image":"","calendar_id":"1",
 "id":"284","level_id":"2","title":"Middle Schools"},

{"school_id":"462","name":"Roosevelt","phone":"","email":"",
 "address":"","information":"","image":"","calendar_id":"1",
"id":"288","level_id":"2","title":"Middle Schools"},

 {"school_id":"468","name":"SCPA","phone":"","email":"",
"address":"","information":"","image":"","calendar_id":"1",
"id":"294","level_id":"2","title":"Middle Schools"},

{"school_id":"478","name":"Standley","phone":"","email":"",
"address":"","information":"","image":"","calendar_id":"1",
 "id":"304","level_id":"2","title":"Middle Schools"},

 {"school_id":"431","name":"Muir","phone":"","email":"",
    "address":"","information":"","image":"","calendar_id":"1",
 "id":"258","level_id":"3","title":"High Schools"},

   {"school_id":"439","name":"O'Farrell","phone":"","email":"",
 "address":"","information":"","image":"","calendar_id":"1",
"id":"267","level_id":"3","title":"High Schools"},


 {"school_id":"452","name":"Point Loma","phone":"","email":"",
 "address":"","information":"","image":"","calendar_id":"1",
"id":"278","level_id":"3","title":"High Schools"},

 {"school_id":"454","name":"Preuss","phone":"","email":"",
"address":"","information":"","image":"","calendar_id":"1",
 "id":"281","level_id":"3","title":"High Schools"},


{"school_id":"466","name":"San Diego","phone":"","email":"","address":"",
 "information":"","image":"","calendar_id":"1",
"id":"292","level_id":"3","title":"High Schools"}]}
```

Answer (score 1):

You traverse the JSON object until you have the correct item. There is no inbuilt function for this. You can find all required methods in the [API](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html).

I would not use JSONObject. It's far easier to use [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org) with annotations.